# Hide elements with similar names in AdBlock Plus

Tags: adblock

[AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) is a very popular browser extension for hiding advertisements in web pages.

It will block page elements based in certain rules, usually defined in subscription files updated autmatically. As no general solution is universally perfect, sometimes it lets a few ADs pass.

In these cases I need to manually define new rules. I use a quite handy helper extension for this, [Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/), that offers GUI capabilities for rule creations.

[image]

My problem is when I try to create a single rule that will apply for multiple cases. For instance, I want to hide elements with class `.publicidade`, `.publicidade-extra`, `.outrapublicidade`, and so on.

How do I create a custom rule for hiding elements with a certain word in its `class` name? Do I need to use regexes? I've read [the official AdBlock Plus cheat sheet](https://adblockplus.org/en/filter-cheatsheet#elementhiding) but it's not clear to me on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it: `##[class*="publicidade"]`

It will affect all elements, on all pages, with "publicidade" in the class name.